# Set GUI inaccessible

Tags: matlab-guide

I have a parent gui with a child, which plays the role of settings for the former. Then  I want to prevent the user from accessing the parent gui when the settings gui is open, like every software does. How am I supposed to do that?

Best

Comment: I "dialog" which grabs control is called "modal".  See if matlab can do a modal dialog.

Comment: Thank you! The modal mode actually does that. But is there anyway that allows only certain guis to be unreachable when it's open?